# Is it necessary to set [DirectoryIndex] while not using index.php?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, directory, indexing

My sites root access is managed by htaccess: it redirects various aliases to their own home files `/en/home` for english `/de/home` for Deutsch etcettera. Previously, I used index.php to route and redirect all that, and hence the DirectoryIndex had something like this:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

Now, however, there is no index.php file, so I commented it

```
# DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

Would it be better to uncomment is and set it to the default /en/home  (with or without .php because in this case?  I have set up rules sohat my pages in browser also work when no extension is given)

```
DirectoryIndex /en/home
```

In all the above cases, my websites work fine and I don't see ANY change when I set either of the three instances as above. but ... "there's gotta be one best ain't it?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the rules written in .htaccess it is best not to repeat the rules in whatever php config and routing functions you are using.  Routing through apache (your .htaccess) is much faster than subverting routes through php, though you will not realize the gains without a pretty high volume of traffic.

Comment: Does that mean I can go ahead and delete the entire DIrectoryIndex line since 301 redirects are in place which will take folks to the right file anyway?